# How to Duplicate SDXC Memory Cards on the Go without a Laptop?

Tags: storage, backup

**Is there a portable device which can copy one memory card into another card without the need for a laptop, ultra-book, netbook or computer?**

Could an Android phone control 2 card readers or a dual-slot SDXC reader to backup one memory card full of images into another?

Unfortunately, my favorite device lost its useful as it does work with SDXC cards. Previously, I used the Addonics MFR to copy memory cards unto DVDs while travelling. Now that I have SDXC cards, DVD and Blu-Rays are too small, so I would like to backup each SDXC card onto another of the same size. For practical reasons, I would like to avoid taking my ultra-book while traveling.

Comment: I'm not sure if the single USB port on the phone will support two card readers. Also not sure if two cards will show up as two different storages on the phone.    ...BUT I just googled SD card copier and saw something might be useful to you..

Comment: Interesting, I had searched for this before but I am only finding portable duplicators up to SDHC, not SDXC. Seems like companies haven't been putting much effort catching up with the times :(

Comment: Another option would be backing up onto a portable hard drive. There are some portable hard drives with SD card readers built in.

Comment: @vclaw - Yeah, the SSD part makes it sturdy which is great but I generally avoid storing my backups on an expensive device since theft is the mostly cause of loss. Having extra SDXC cards or even a USB key are very easy to conceal and they won't appear so valuable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a [Transcend RDP9](https://www.transcend-info.com/Products/No-630) card reader/hub to transfer from SD card to a thumb drive. I would assume you could instead plug a second card reader into the hub's USB receptacle. I don't use it with SDXC cards, but the manufacturer claims that they are supported. Check the phone compatibility list, though... some older phones don't have fully-functional OTG support.

UPDATE: I had a chance to actually try plugging [my other SD card reader](https://www.transcend-info.com/Products/No-396) into the USB port on this one, and it worked fine, allowing card-to-card transfer. Of course, YMMV...

Comment: Can these things be daisy-chained? My phone only has one micro USB port and if I put in a hub, then there won't be any more micro-USB ports, so I'm confused.

Comment: It has card slots on one side, and a USB A receptacle on the other, so you can mount a card and a thumb drive at the same time, and move files between any combination of phone, drive, and card.

Comment: Cool! That sounds fantastic. Just ordered one, let's see if it works.

Comment: Nice one! It unfortunately does not work on my phone but I managed with another, so it works.

Answer (score 0):

I successfully used [StickMount Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.stickmount.pro) (is needed to be able to connect more than one device) on my Android Phone and a small USB Hub connected with an OTG cable for a similar purpose. Obviously, two small card readers are also needed.

You have to try if your phone can power the Hub and the two readers, otherwise you need a powered hub. With a powered hub, it's even possible to attach external Hard drives (I was doing that).

Note: you need a rooted device.

Comment: A short internet search reveals, that there are dual card readers, that might replace the hub, but I did not try that.

Comment: Interesting. If this is as flexible as it sounds, I could use a reader to get the card and plug a flash key to copy multiple cards into it too... or two readers which I have.

Comment: That should work, yes